# MYSQL - If exists update else insert not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I am trying to use query of condition IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT and its sending multiple records at one time using for loop. Code through which its sending values is:

```
if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
    $eOffId = $_POST['off'];
    $startHr = $_POST['stHr'];
    $startMi = $_POST['st-mi'];
    $startMe = $_POST['st-me'];
    $endHr = $_POST['en-hr'];
    $endMi = $_POST['en-mi'];
    $endMe = $_POST['en-me'];
    $fieldCount = count($_POST['days']);
    $days = $_POST['days'];

    $users->editOffice($eOffId, $loc, $sp, $instructor_id);

    for($i= 0; $i <= (count($days)); $i++) { 
         $daysOfWeek = implode(', ', $days[$i]);
         $starts = $startHr[$i].":".$startMi[$i]." ".$startMe[$i];
         $ends = $endHr[$i].":".$endMi[$i]." ".$endMe[$i];
         $dbId = $_POST['time'][$i];
         $eOffId = $_POST['off'];

        $users->editTimings($dbID, $daysOfWeek, $starts, $ends, $eOffId );

   }  
 }
```

MYSQL Query

```
   public function editTimings($dbId, $daysOfWeek, $starts, $ends, $eOffId ){
     $editTimings_query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `dyc_instructor_office_hours` (`office_hour_id`, `days`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `office_location_id`)  VALUES (:dbId, :daysOfWeek, :starts, :ends, :eOffId) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `days` = :daysOfWeek, `start_time` = :starts, `end_time` = :ends, `office_location_id` = :eOffId");

     $editTimings_query->bindValue(':dbId', $dbId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $editTimings_query->bindValue(':daysOfWeek', $daysOfWeek, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $editTimings_query->bindValue(':starts', $starts, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $editTimings_query->bindValue(':ends', $ends, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $editTimings_query->bindValue(':eOffId', $eOffId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

 try{
    $editTimings_query->execute();
  }catch(PDOException $e){
 }
 }
```

Here is the data in database
[image]

The problem is, its only inserting the records instead of updating, query is fine as I tested it separately by updating one record but when I am using it in code it is just inserting records instead of updating which already exists.

Your suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Thank You,
Kind Regards.

Comment: Your keys must not be duplicates then. We can't help you without your data. [mcve]

Comment: No they are not duplicate, office_hour_id is primary key and auto increment.

Comment: Make sure that [emulation mode is not turned off](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation) or your query won't work. BTW, you can use `values()` keyword instead of providing the actual values on DUPLICATE part

Comment: @YourCommonSense But the query is working when I used it separately in phpmyadmin.

Comment: phpmyadmin has absolutely nothing to do here.

Comment: And the data you're adding.....?

Comment: ouch, just realized that you are using empty try..catch here. That's the root of the problem. [Get rid of all the try-catch](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#errors) in this code and run again.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, its in the same format like Days: Monday, Tuesday -- start_time: 8:00 A.M, end_time: 12:00 P.M, instructor_id: 1, different records in the same pattern at a time are inserting and updating the table. The code I am showing is the code from edit records page where user can edit old records and can also add new one if needed.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: In what way is that the root of the problem?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet in [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=debugging)

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Wow that was helpful thanks

Comment: @YourCommonSense you mean, I should remove try and catch and just simply execute the query?

Comment: @YourCommonSense removing try and catch is not working.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am  already using this statement to check errors $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); but its not throwing any error.

Comment: look, there are only two cases possible: either the query worked, or there was an error. There is no other possible result. So, if the query didn't work, then there should be an error. Make sure you can see PHP errors in general.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, thanks for your suggestion. I will check it again in detail. Thank you.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, can you help me in this regard. I have a confusion, query is working as it is inserting data into table but not updating. Is there any problem with syntax of query I have written?

Comment: if it works, then there is apparently no problem with syntax

Comment: @YourCommonSense, thanks your suggestions helps a lot.

Comment: @YourCommonSense your suggestion about using error reporting works. Thanks a lot. You saved my day.